# Как заполнить массив структур с полем char*?

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Есть структура:

```
typedef struct Word {

unsigned int code; // код слова 
char * value; // значение
} Word;
```

и есть массив структур

```
Word * dictionary [4096];
```

Для заполнения такой код:

```
// заполняем первые 256 слов словаря 
// память под значение слова и \0
char * iv  = malloc (2 * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
 iv [0] = i;
 iv [1] = '\0';
 // копируем  строку в словарь
 dictionary[i]->code = i;
 strcpy (dictionary[i]->value, iv);
}
free (iv); 
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) printf ("значение слова : \t %s", dictionary[i]->value);
```

Получаю программный краш. Думаю, это из-за того, что поле value может занимать сколько угодно байт и malloc не знает, сколько памяти выделять. Как правильно заполнять такие массивы?

Теперь заполняю массив так:

```
char * iv  = malloc (2 * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
 iv [0] = i;
 iv [1] = '\0';
 dictionary[i]-> value = malloc (2 *sizeof(char)); // выделяем память
 strcat (dictionary[i]->value, iv);
}
free (iv); 
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){ 
    printf ("имя %s", dictionary[i]->value);
    free (dictionary[i]->value); // освобождаем память
}
```

Но это не решило проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А выделять память в структуре? Если у вас все "слова" по одному символу - ну напишите не `char*value`, а `char value[2]` и копируйте прямо в него...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
  // копируем  строку в словарь
  dictionary[i]->code = i;
  dictionary[i]->value[0] = (char)i;
  dictionary[i]->value[0] = 0;
}
```

Всяко размер 2 байта даже меньше указателя - экономим память! :)

Если же вы планируете какие-то реально большие слова писать - то выделяйте память

```
dictionary[i]->value = malloc(....
strcpy(dictionary[i]->value, ....
```

Только не забудьте потом ее освободить.

Comment: У меня первые 256 символов только по 1 байту, а другие  могут быть какие угодно. Пытаюсь реализовать LZW .Поэтому нужен динамический массив символов для значения.

Comment: Ну вот - вы же сами пишете "Нужен динамический массив" - ну так выделяете его. То, что у меня идет вторым вариантом.

Comment: все равно программа крашится... память освобождаю в том же цикле. Сейчас обновлю код в вопросе.

Comment: Да что ж вы творите-то! Освобождать - потом, когда поработали и она не нужна, а не сразу же после того, как в нее записали!

Comment: Да, вы правы, освободил после вывода на консоль, но все равно вывода нет...

Comment: Похоже, не выделяете память для Word`. Хотя зачем вы объявляете именно массив указателей `Word*`, не пойму... Да и `strcat` тут не в тему. Короче, достало, нате работающий код - https://ideone.com/KRFPPK , и на этом хватит, ладно?